# Optional parameter in SQL with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

Given the optional parameter in the following SQL, I'm trying to do the following: if @fiCode is an empty string, then I want the parameter to be ignored. However, if it contains a value then I want to see if it within the list generated by this subquery: SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(r.bo_type, ',')

```
SELECT * --d.boclient_id, r.doc_id 
FROM @tab_Rules r, @BOData d
WHERE d.bo_type IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(r.bo_type, ','))
AND 1 = 
(
CASE 
    WHEN @fiCode = '' THEN 1
    ELSE @fiCode <> '' AND @fiCode IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(r.fi_code, ',')) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Carl

Comment: Also suggest re-writing `FROM @tab_Rules r, @BOData d
WHERE ` --> `FROM @tab_Rules AS r INNER JOIN @BOData AS d
ON `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `ELSE`s - the first one should be `WHEN` instead. But I think that this is easier expressed with boolean logic:

```
AND (
    @ficode = '' 
    OR @ficode IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(r.fi_code, ','))
(
```